# Change input given value to a custom value in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am very new to ReactJS, I'm trying to type inside the input field however, it is overriding only 1 number then the cursor disappears, I want the curosor ro stay so I can type as much numbers as I want.
I've watched several tutorials however non of them worked in my case.
Appreciate your assistance regarding this matter

```
this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)

this.state = {
  coordinatesList: [
     [29.294957293, 30.1027401502],
     [30.193056150, 26.1047492638]
]
}

//coordinatesList returns a an array list of arrays with 2 index
// I want to display each index seperatly, that's why I used item[0]

<SortableContainer coordinatesList={this.state.coordinatesList} drag= 
 {this.handleDragging}>
      {this.state.coordinatesList.map((item, index) => (
        <SortableItem
          key={item}
          index={index}
          className="sortable-item"
        >
          <SortIcon />
          <input onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e, 
index)} type="text" value={item[0]} />
        </SortableItem>
      ))}
    </SortableContainer>


handleInputChange(e, index){
 let updatedState = [...this.state.coordinatesList];
 updatedState[index] = [Number(e.target.value), 
 this.state.coordinatesList[index][1]]
 
 this.vectorLayer.clear();
 apiRegistry
  .getApis(["Feature"])
  .then(([Feature]) => {
    var feature = new Feature({
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [this.state.coordinatesList]
      },
      "properties": {
      }
    })
    this.vectorLayer.addFeature(feature);
    this.setState({
      coordinatesList: updatedState
    })
  });
```

}

Comment: I'm a little confused how its not giving an error? `handleInputChange` changes `this.state.coordinatesList` to be a string but you're mapping over it as if it were an array.

Comment: `value={"x: " + item[0]}` this is also probably not going to do what you expect. You should make a label for the input instead.

Comment: What populates `coordinatesList`? You're going to need to provide more context, after the update I still dont see how this could work, and you're still changing the data type of `coordinatesList` in the change handler.

Answer (score 1):

Here is yours solution

```
<SortableContainer coordinatesList={this.state.coordinatesList} drag={this.handleDragging}>
      {this.state.coordinatesList.map((item, index) => (
        <SortableItem
          key={item}
          index={index}
          className="sortable-item"
        >
          <SortIcon />
          <input onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e, index)} type="text" value={`x: ${item[0]}`} />
        </SortableItem>
      ))}
    </SortableContainer>

   handleInputChange(e, index){
     let updatedState = [...this.state.coordinatesList];
     updatedState[index] = Number(e.target.value)
     this.setState({
       coordinatesList: updatedState
     })
   }
```

Comment: You should include an explanation of what your code does differently. Generally a code only answer is not considered a good one.

Comment: In addition, the answer mutates state: `let updatedState = this.state.coordinatesList;`.

Comment: @Shubham The point is that state should never be mutated directly; it can lead to difficult-to-trace behavior problems.

Comment: here state are not mutating directly. I've took a variable and assigned the state to it and if you see the next statement I'm updating the state with updatedState variable.

Comment: @Shubham That's a common mistake, but because of how JavaScript arrays work, that is still mutating the original. You need to create a completely new array instead of assigning the reference: `let updatedState = [...this.state.coordinatesList];`

Comment: @Brian I've updated it in the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've tried it out, however the list that I want to update is a list of integers, so this way it gets converted to a string, also, the cursor inside the input tag disappears when I adjust one number

Comment: okay that has done part of the job however there are two issues, first one is that it updates the whole array for the selected index not only index[0], also, the input allows me to put only one value then updates, I want to be able to put as much values as I want

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a simple way to do that now. You can use this code to update input.

```
class Input extends Component {
  state = {
    yourInput: '',
  };

  handleInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({yourInput: e.target.value});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.state.yourInput}</h2>
        <input onChange={this.handleInput} value={this.state.yourInput} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Try to modify your code based on this for the simplicity.